# How to prevent Chrome from restoring last session?

Tags: chrome-for-android

Whenever I close and reopen Chrome it automatically restores the last session. How do I stop it, so that on reopen it should open homepage instead of last session?

I'm using Android Marshmallow and my Chrome version is the latest one (updated today).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was possible in earlier versions but from Chrome version 51 onwards, it is not possible as it *designed* to open in last session instead of home page

I couldn't find any workaround for rooted devices on net

**[Source](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/aMkxSvV8s78/8MbnST7cBAAJ)**

Answer (score 2):

Instead of closing Chrome close all the pages that are open. It looks like a square with a number in it on my phone, next to the address bar, at the top of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

On Chrome close all but one page, set the address as "about:blank" (without the quotes and then form the menu select "Add to home screen". You can then open that with no embarrasment! lol